# I am getting an "Unexpected token" error when trying to do JSON.parse on a simple object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
var a = localStorageService.get('selectedQuestionSortOrder');
$scope.selectedQuestionOrderBy = JSON.parse(a);
var b = 99;
```

When I look with the debugger I see:

```
a
-
Object
key: "questionStatusId"
label: "status"
```

After I execute the second line I get the message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at new <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:81/Content/app/admin/controllers/question-controller.js:71:47)
    at d (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.1.5.min.js:28:304)
    at Object.instantiate (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.1.5.min.js:28:434)
    at $get (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.1.5.min.js:53:326)
    at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.1.5.min.js:44:274
    at n (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.1.5.min.js:7:74)
    at k (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.1.5.min.js:44:139)
    at e (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.1.5.min.js:40:139)
    at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.1.5.min.js:39:205
```

Can someone give me some advice as to what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need of `JSON.parse(a);` since `a` is already an Object.